# Is it possible to use an audio file as multiple choice answer items or question in an Alexa quiz skill?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to write a quiz skill for an unsupported language (Mandarin). An example quiz (if it was in English) will look like the following:

```
Q: what is the smallest natural number?
A: a. 0; b. 1; c. 2
```

(But I wanted the skill reads the question and multiple choice in mandarin)

Since Alexa does not support Chinese as a language, I wonder if I can use recorded audio files as the input -- if it's possible, then I can have my skill play the audio file (a blob) for the quiz input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use an audio file up to 4 minutes long instead of text to speech using an SSML audio tag.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/speech-synthesis-markup-language-ssml-reference.html#audio

Comment: Thanks, this help a lot!